# Symfony2 DoctrineMongoDBBundle: Getting empty result after creating Repository classes

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

Sorry for the long question, but i think its simple for experienced symfony and mongodb developer.
Q: If i generate repository class, all repository `findAll(), findBy(), findOneBy(), findBy*()` gets failed. Why it fails? 
below my composer state.

```
"require":
 {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.11.3",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.1",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.2"
    }
```

Controller method as below

```
     /**
     * @Route("survey/{token}", name="survey_index")
     */
    public function indexAction($token){
        // if i remove repository, below query gives perfect result.
        $survey = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
        ->getRepository('CoreBundle:Survey')->findAll();

        return $this->render('CoreBundle:Survey:index.html.twig',array('survey'=>$survey));
    }
```

Document class as below

```
namespace CoreBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/**
 * @ODM\Document(collection="survey_master")
 * @ODM\Document(repositoryClass="CoreBundle\Repository\SurveyRepository")
 */
class Survey {

    /**
     * @ODM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

// setters and getters below
}
```

**If I remove**

`* @ODM\Document(repositoryClass="CoreBundle\Repository\SurveyRepository")`

**and perform cache clear, everything works perfect.**

SurveyRepository class

```
namespace CoreBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository;

/**
 * SurveyRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ODM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class SurveyRepository extends DocumentRepository
{


}
```

Comment: How all the methods fail?

Comment: @martin it returns empty array `[]` for `findAll()`. If i remove repository it gives perfect result.

Comment: `Survey` has two annotations with `@ODM\Document` which I think override themselves. Can you try putting both parameters to a single annotation?

Comment: @martin Ok. I trying it and let you know.

Comment: like this `* @ODM\Document(collection="survey_master",repositoryClass="CoreBundle\Repository\SurveyRepository")` , right ?

Comment: @martin You saved my day. Put it in answer i will accept it. Thank You :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132101/discussion-between-jagad89-and-martin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Survey has two annotations with `@ODM\Document` which override themselves.

Put both parameters to a single annotation.